# Using viewport to force all screens to 640px wide

Tags: css, responsive-design, viewport

I am trying to force all mobile devices to have a rendered screen size of 640px wide.  I've used:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=640">`

Unfortunately, when I emulate screen resolutions in Chrome, the page sizes completely differently between different devices.

If I emulate a Note 3, it looks far different than an iPhone 4.

I've also tried doing:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">`

But this only works for any screen who's initial scale or pixel ratio is set correctly.  For example, the note3 has to be set to `initial-scale=.5623` for the page to look like it's 640px wide, but that's not the case for the iphone.

What am I missing??

Comment: Why? Fixed width is terrible.

Comment: And what if the viewport isn't 640px wide??

Comment: @bjb568 Fixed width **is** terrible, yes.  I am trying to force all mobile devices to show 640px wide because that's the requirement.  I'm only doing what's told of me.  Is there a solution?

Comment: @bjb568 thanks for the help. If I couldn't, I wouldn't

Comment: Are you resizing an entire-website or setting up a document for 'fresh' html and css?

Comment: @lindsay unfortunately, I'm resizing an entire website.  I have to use the existing HTML and make it 'responsive'

Comment: @ntgCleaner hmm... that is really tricky. I can only suggest trying to these two (untested) methods. One is to try query what device is accessing the page with JavaScript, and set the meta tag for the viewport that most accurately achieves the 640 'look'. Second if you have to use the html markup in place and make it 640px wide, make your outermost container a fixed width of 640 and do your best to go from there.

Comment: @lindsay, Thank you for the suggestions.  I'm currently doing #2 where I made the entire content 640px wide.  I've tested the pages on different devices and it seems to be working properly with my first example in the post.  What was worrying me is the screen emulation in Chrome.  It places a bunch of strange characteristics that you can adjust - these are rarely set to be what they should be!

Comment: @ntgCleaner Ah okay! I've never put too much stock in the Chrome emulation. If you've got a smart phone and usb cable handy, I'd recommend using the mobile debugging tools within Chrome (if you're not familiar with those already).